# Specify start date and end date using Alpha Vantage API Python

Tags: python, api, alpha-vantage

How do I specify a start date and end date? For example, I want to extract daily close price for AAPL from 01-01-2020 to 30-06-2021?

```
enter code here
from alpha.vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd

api_key = ''
ts = TimeSeries(key = api_key, output_format = 'pandas')
data - ts.get_daily('AAPL', outputsize = 'full')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on their [documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#daily), it doesn't seem to have an option to filter by date directly in the API call.

Once you retrieve the data you can filter it within the dataframe.

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import pandas as pd

api_key = ''
ts = TimeSeries(key = api_key, output_format = 'pandas')
data = ts.get_daily('AAPL', outputsize = 'full')
data[0][(data[0].index >= '2020-01-01') & (data[0].index <= '2021-06-30')]
```

output:

[image]

---

You can also use .loc when filtering the data since date is the index, but this is deprecated and it will throw an error in a future version of pandas.

```py
data[0].loc['2020-01-01':'2021-06-30']
```